# How can I set a (non-global) variable in a jinja context function?

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to set variable values, but only when they are not already assigned and within a local context.

So there is a solution to this:

```
{% with x=( x | default(1)) %}
    {{ x }}
{% endwith %}

{% with x=2 %}
    {% with x=( x | default(1)) %}
        {{ x }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

This works nicely but it is a lot of text. I have many situations where I don't have just one but up to 20 variables that are being set and then a macro is called, or a template is included with those values.

Writing all those default conditions is just a mess and provokes mistakes. So I would love to be able to set a value on the current context in e.g. in a context function. But if I try the following:

```
@contextfunction
def defaults(ctx, **vals):
    for k,v in vals.iteritems():
      if k not in ctx:
          ctx[k] = v
```

I get the an exception:

> TypeError: 'Context' object does not support item assignment

And trying to set a value on ctx.vars would not help either:

> **vars**
>   The template local variables. This list contains environment and context functions from the parent scope as well as local
>   modifications and exported variables from the template. The template
>   will modify this dict during template evaluation but filters and
>   context functions are not allowed to modify it.
>   http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.Context.vars

I tried with

```
@contextfunction
def defaults(ctx, **vals):
    for k,v in vals.iteritems():
         if k not in ctx.vars:
             ctx.vars[k] = v
```

And it gives no exception but just seems to not assign the value to the context.

I know I could write to the global context but that's not what I would like to do as it would produce side effects.

Is there a possibility to get just the current context and set a value on it? I didn't find any instructions on it and how this could be done and I did not really grasp that from reading the jinja source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, somehow I keep solving my own problems. It is not exactly an answer to the question of *"How can I set a (non-global) variable in a jinja context function?"*, but it solves the problem.

I have written a jinja extension, that allows for a simple "default" tag:

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

"""
    DefaultExtension
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Very simple jinja extension that allows for the following 

    {% set x=(x | default(1)) %}
    {% set y=(y | default(2)) %}

    to be written as 

    {% default x=1, y=2 %}

    :copyright: (c) 2017 by the Roman Seidl
    :license: BSD
"""

class DefaultExtension(Extension):
    # a set of names that trigger the extension.
    tags = set(['default'])

    def parse(self, parser):
        #just dump the tag
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno

        #parse through assignments (similar to parser.parse_with)
        assignments = []
        while parser.stream.current.type != 'block_end':
            lineno = parser.stream.current.lineno
            if assignments:
                parser.stream.expect('comma')
            target = parser.parse_assign_target()
            parser.stream.expect('assign')
            expr = (parser.parse_expression())
            #consruct a 'default' filter
            filter = nodes.Filter(nodes.Name(target.name, 'load'), 'default', [expr], [], None, None, lineno=lineno)
            #produce an assignment with this filter as value
            assignment = nodes.Assign(target, filter, lineno=lineno)
            assignments.append(assignment)
      return assignments
```

I just had to add it to my app:

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension(DefaultExtension)
```

and it works quite nicely, though I must confess I haven't yet tested it very thoroughly.

Anyone think I should submit this to jinja?